# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Song with id=attention-let-me-go-remix):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why am I getting this now? A new user uploaded a song, I went to vote it up and I'm getting the following: (this happened after I created staging branch)

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Song with id=attention-let-me-go-remix):
2013-08-14T06:11:31.740608+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:13:in `vote_for'
```

**song controller snippit**

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create ,:edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]

  def extract_video

  @song = Song.find(params[:id])
  @song.YouTubeAddy.extract_video_id

  end

  def vote_for
      @song = Song.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(@song)
      @song.plusminus = @song.votes_for
      @song.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'update_votes' }
      end
  end

  def vote_against
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_against(@song)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'update_votes' }
    end
  end

  def new_songs
    @songs = Song.order("id DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    get_last_song
  end


  # GET /Songs
  # GET /Songs.json
  def index
    if params[:query].present? 
      @songs = Song.search(params)
      get_last_song
    elsif params[:genre]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:genre]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    else      
      @songs = Song.order('id').order('plusminus desc nulls last').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15) 
      #@songs = Song.tally.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
      get_last_song
    end
  end


  def get_last_song
    if params[:page].nil?
      @last_song = 0
    else
      @last_song = 15 * (params[:page].to_i - 1)
    end
  end

  # GET /Songs/1
  # GET /Songs/1.json
  def show
   @comment = Comment.new(song: @song) 
   @video_tag = YouTubeAddy.extract_video_id(@song.url)

  end

  # GET /Songs/new
  def new
    @song = Song.new
  end

  # GET /Songs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /Songs
  # POST /Songs.json
  def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)
    @song.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.save
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @song }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**schema snippit**

```
 create_table "songs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "artist"
    t.text     "url"
    t.string   "track_file_name"
    t.string   "track_content_type"
    t.integer  "track_file_size"
    t.datetime "track_updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "plusminus"
    t.string   "slug"
  end
```

Comment: post the full logs for the action in order to see what params exactly you are sending and what params are being processed by controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@song = Song.find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

or if you want to find your song by id you'll have to use in your link for vote `song.id`:

```
  vote_for_song_path(song.id)
```

now you can use:

```
 @song = Song.find(params[:id])
```

in controller.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to change it to `@song = Song.find_by_url(params[:id])`

Comment: Yeah. The problem actually should be in your vote for url. You are passing in the slug instead of the `@song.id`.

Comment: wtf, getting this now :/ --  app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:14:in `vote_for'
2013-08-14T06:26:01.844770+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "voteable_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: You need to make sure you @song exists. Try in the console to search for the song. For example: `@song = Song.find_by_url("attention-let-me-go-remix")`. The reason you're getting that error might be `@song` is `nil`.

Comment: Also, try this `@song = Song.find_by_slug(params[:id])`.

Comment: can i just git back to when it was working..because this is a nasty bug.

Comment: Of course. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/git-revert-to-previous-commit-how

Answer (score -1):

You can do this too

```
@song = Song.all.where(:url => params[:id])
```

that find_by_attribute thing doesn't seemed to work in my case.

Comment: That's wrong (no offence): It should be `@song = Song.where(:url => params[:id]).first`.

Comment: @BenjaminTan it isin't wrong sir, url is unique so we don need to use `.first` and `Song.all.where` and `Song.where` will lead to the same result one way or another.

Comment: Song.all returns an Array, not an Active Relation. You cannot call `where` on an array.

Comment: @BenjaminTan it just returns a subset of all the records as Active Relation and all operations can be performed on it. In case of 'all' all the data will be returned in the Active Relation form only, not array. try printing `p Song.all.class' you will get Active Relation only.

Comment: What Rails version are you using? AFAIK, Rails 3 returns an Array on `#all`. Please look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class carefully. `1.9.3-p0-falcon :001 > Spree::User.all.class
 => Array`

Comment: @BenjaminTan My apologies, I must have had some confusion, You were Right. Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Comment: No problem! It took a while for me to understand that too.